# How to change Drupals menu alternatives for creating a page

Tags: drupal, organic-groups, drupal-permissions

I have a Drupal site with Organic Groups and I want one group to be able to access the menu options and place the page in the primary_links menu where ever they want. The other group shouldn't be able to access it at all.

I have accomplished some of this with privileges, but the user who has access to the menus have access to *all* menus. I just want them to have access to the *Primary Links* menu.

How can i make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using the menus as blocks, you can define what roles are allowed to see each block.

Also, you could adopt [one of the quite many access control modules](http://drupalmodules.com/search/node/access+category%3A24) that Drupal offers for nodes, since a node that the user is not allowed to see will not show up in his menu.

Also, you could write code to switch around which of the menus (you can create as many as you want) is considered for primary links based on what role the user has.

Note that there's a difference between the menu which name is by default *Primary Links* and the setting of which menu should be used for "primary links" on the actual page. The normal place for configuring this is `admin/build/menu/settings`, but it can be easily overridden by messing with the global `$conf` array in settings.php. I think the setting is called something like `'menu_primary_links_source'`.